# Can we control bluetooth programmaticaly in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, controls, bluetooth

I have heard about bluetooth via GameKit and external accesory framework in iPhone . But I don't know much about it . So Before reading the whole documents I just want to know that can we control bluetooth programmaticaly in iPhone .

Thanks .,

Comment: How about just reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking if you can programmatically control arbitrary bluetooth devices, then the answer is no. GameKit uses bluetooth, but it abstracts all the details away from the app. The External Accessory framework only is for use for items that are part of the Made For iPhone program, which requires the device to authenticate using a special protocol (you can find out more by joining the program).